# Countdown function

Tags: javascript, loops, countdown

I am writing code to try and create a countdown function in the console. I want the code to continue to run 5 times and then end with the phrase "Finished!" When I run this code as is it stops after one time. Am I supposed to add a while function to get it to run 5 consecutive times? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var i = 5;

function startTimer() {
  var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(i);
    
    i = i - 1;

    if (i <= 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownTimer);
      console.log("Finished!");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

Comment: What loop? Your code seems to work fine?

Comment: You mean you want 5 consecutive count downs?

Comment: Your code works, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted your countdown to run 5 times you could do it just like this:
I´d say the code changes are pretty self explaining

```js
var i = 5;
var k = 5;
function startTimer() {
  var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(i);
    
    i = i - 1;

    if (i <= 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownTimer);
      console.log("Finished!");
      k = k - 1;
      if(k > 0 ){
          i = 5;
          startTimer();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```